# Does Openshift allow yum on scalable applications

Tags: permissions, openshift, yum

When I attempt to install a package on my openshift using yum, I get the following error

```
    error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
    CRITICAL:yum.main:

    Error: rpmdb open failed
```

when I try to run rpm, I get the following:

```
    bash: /bin/rpm: Permission denied
```

Am I correct to assume that the installation of packages is disallowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, user accounts do not have the ability to install packages using the yum utility.